# DataTables - not load all data at once?

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I have a question about the JQuery PlugIn DataTables.

My Table have got over 5000 rows and it takes more than 20 sec to load the site, and I don't want that.

I wanted to ask if it is possible to only load the first 10 rows and then with pagination click "next" and it loads the next 10 rows?

I know how to do it with my own php code, but I would like to keep using DataTables.

Comment: there are some tutorials around for DataTables `lazy-loading`, you gotta look after one for the version you're using

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

Answer (score 5):

Basically for that, it's preferable to use Ajax/server-side processing. Turn on the server-side by adding params below to your datatable javascript:

```
"bServerSide": true, //turn on server-side processing
"sAjaxSource": "ajax.php" //ajax source
```

For ajax.php, refer to the sample code here -
[DataTables server-side processing example](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)